# How to unsubscribe multiple observables in angular component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

What is the best strategy to **unsubscribe** multiple observable in angular? Just to be clear I use this approach when the application *is not big* and do not need solutions such as **ngrx** that in this case would be an **overengineering**.

Currently I use a subscription instance to add all subscriptions and after that when the component was destroyed i call the unsubscribe method. But also I have seen alternatives using the **takeUntil** from **rxjs**.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  $firstObservable: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
  $secondObservable: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);

  private _subscriptions = new Subscription();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._subscriptions .unsubscribe();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._subscriptions .add(
      this.$firstObservable.subscribe(console.log));

    this._subscriptions .add(
      this.$secondObservable.subscribe(console.log));
  }

}
```

What would be the best solution?

Comment: You can merge all those subscriptions to one `.subscribe`

Comment: `takeUntil` is currently considered to be the best practice.

Comment: Using `takeUntil` is the easiest way you can do. Btw, you can chain `this._subscriptions.add().add().add()` calls which makes it a little shorter.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to use `takeUntil()` pipeable operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html

This way, you create a `Subject` which is to emit value on `ngOnDestroy` and unsubscribe multiple subscriptions all at once

```
 unsubscribeSignal: Subject<void> = new Subject();

 firstObservable$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
 secondObservable$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);

 ngOnInit() {

    this.firstObservable$
    .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal),
    )
    .subscribe();

    this.secondObservable$
    .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal),
    )
    .subscribe();

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubscribeSignal.next();
    // Don't forget to unsubscribe from the subject itself
    this.unsubscribeSignal.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: As you can see in the link that i share on my last answer. You have to be careful when use takeUntil operator. " We should not forget about the fact that the takeUntil operator has to be last operator in the pipe (usually) to prevent situation when subsequent operator return additional observables which can prevent clean up. - by Brian Love".

Comment: Most examples I've seen of this prefer `complete()` to `unsubscribe()` in `ngOnDestroy`. Although the end result may be the same, that's probably less confusing since we never actually subscribe to it. Also the `asObservable` calls are probably unnecessary overhead (creating an extra object) since `Subject` is already an `Observable`.

Comment: Also I think the convention is to put the `$` at the end of the variable name, not the beginning.

Comment: @Jeremy You're absolutely right and good catch after 4 years! :D Updating accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

I'm very disappointed that people don't even mention the `async` pipe.

It's very powerful, allowing you to both stop worrying about subscriptions and using on push detection strategy.

To use it, simply remove the subscriptions from your TS, and assign the values to your variables which will be typed as observables.

Just look at the code reduction and simplessness (don't know if it's a word, but kinda don't care)

```js
export class MyComponent {
  firstObservable$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
  secondObservable$: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);

  combination$ = combineLatest(this.firstObservable$, this.secondObservable$)
    .pipe(tap(() => console.log()));
}
```

In your HTML

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="combination$ | async">
  Observables are being observed.
</ng-container>
```

(Even though it's not suited to your question example, you can already see how it's way cleaner & simpler)

And best part, you don't have to worry about memory leaks anymore. Angular takes care of all the subscriptions, leaving you to only care about your code (which is what a good framework is supposed to do).

Comment: Yes, the async pipe is very powerful. But there are some cases that you need to subscribe manually.

Comment: @RenatoSantos then provide those cases, not an example like that !

Comment: @trichetriche I've just posted an answer where I refer to a post that shows all the scenarios.

Comment: I know that I am replying to a pretty old post, but there are many situations where you might be subscribing to an observable that is not referenced in the mark-up, for example router events, a data sharing service, etc.  So there are situations where an async pipe is not suitable.

Answer (score 6):

`Subscribe` class has an `add` method that adds multiple subscriptions into one and then it can be `unsubscribed` at once.

```
subscription1 = observable.subscribe(
    // next, err, complete etc
);

subscription2 = observable.subscribe(
    // next, err, complete etc
);
```

adding multiple subscriptions

```
subscription1.add(subscription2);
```

unsubscribing all subscriptions at once.

```
subscription1.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to store the `subscription` object and on `ngDestroy` call unsubscribe method.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  $firstObservable: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
  $secondObservable: Observable<number> = timer(0, 1000);
   
  private _subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._subscriptions.push(
      this.$firstObservable.subscribe(console.log)
    );

    this._subscriptions.push(
      this.$secondObservable.subscribe(console.log)
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe()); // ‍♂️‍♂️
  }

}
```